# Safest way to update record in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building an experimental site for myself in PHP and MySQL.

I'm adding an update record section where my logged in users can update certain records in my table.

To update a record im passing the record id through the URL and updating it using that as my primary key, my problem however (and im well aware this is a massive security issue) is that any user can alter the url variable and update anybody else's information.

Whats the best way to prevent this?

Comment: Only allow **trusted** logged in users to edit. Generally someone can only edit themself and moderators/admins (trusted users) can edit others.

Comment: use POST instead of GET and don't forget to clean all the data before interacting wit the database, use mysqli::real_escape_string(), and use SESSION to handle the current user id.

Comment: @ROMMEL using post does not eliminate the security problem.

Comment: @ROMMEL I've been told several times that you should never "clean" data on its way to the database. You should use Prepared Statements instead.

Comment: prepare/bind > escaping

Comment: @rommel: post is an extremely MINOR security measure, and can be trivially forged by pretty much anyone who can write basic html.

Comment: @gview you're right. At least it's not pretty obvious =)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Prepared Statements are simply harder to mess up.  mysqli_real_escape_string() is sufficient if you remember to always use it and don't do something stupid (like change the character encoding with a query, instead of the PHP function).

Comment: I think the bigger issue here is that the OP is not checking the user for each record.  @liam you should be checking the user first - if he is logged in appropriately, and his user ID is allowed to edit the MYSQL record in question, THEN allow it.  Then way, even if he maliciously changes the GET variables, your app will tell him "sorry sir, you don't have access."

Comment: @Izkata I can't think of a good reason why anyone wouldn't want to use PDO statements.

Answer (score 3):

Well quite simply, your web application needs to know whos information is whose, and return an error page when a user who does not have proper rights tries to do something like that.

Or if you want to be very secure instead of returning a Not Authorized page (this would allow people to figure out information about your database) just return a generic error page whether the URL is valid or not.

EDIT:

As people are pointing out below, you can tell who a user is through basic PHP session management, but I had assumed you already knew how to tell WHO the user sending the request is.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to start by creating a session variable to hold the logged in user id (and username, and whatever...)

```
<?php
     session_start();
     //store session data
     $_SESSION['userid']=$auth->userid();
?>
```

Then create a function loaded globally or as a apart of an authentication class that will use the user id of the currently logged in user to check if it matches a user id in the database.

```
 function permissible($userid) {
         if ($userid != $SESSION['userid']) {
              header('Location: http://www.404.com/'); //redirect to suitable location
         }
    }
```

Now, use like this in your code at the top of a php file

```
permissible($GET['userid']);
```

This is just an example. Remember to replace the variables with the proper ones.

Comment: This is the theory, but to do this correctly is not easy at all. It's probably better to use a framework that provides this implementation.

Comment: This is quick and easy code. My answer was catered specifically  to answer this question

Comment: Quite simply, if the id from the uri does not match the id of the userid stored in session, the user can execute the action.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way is to utilize session variables upon login.  If for example, you have a script that updates a member row like:  updatemember.php?id=8

You modify this script so that rather than getting id from $_GET['id'], you instead get id from the session.

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Of course this assumes that $_SESSION['user_id'] was populated when the user first authenticated, and was logged in, but this is a fairly standard technique, where the basic information for a user gets read from the database and stored in one or more session variables upon successful login.

In summary, the use of php sessions solve the problem of understanding "who is this user trying to do this right now?"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the user edits, for example, if he edits his own data, you can do smth like the people above me have suggested, or even more, don't post/get his id,just do "update data . . . . . . . . where userid=$_SESSION['user_id'], but if he edit some other information, like his blog post for example, you will have to select the edit blog post, and then check to see if he is the poster (owner, what ever you want to call it), and then if $poster_id==$current_logged_in_user_id edit, else redirect, throw error ot what ever, just don't edit the blog post (in this case)

Answer (score -1):

In order to protect your site from people misusing id variable in the url, You will have to allow only registered users to do update operation, you can also create a history table in which you will save the old state of the row and mention who changed it and when, another way is to create rules and permissions where users can only update the data that they inserted, and you could add administrator roles which can update data that belongs to everybody.

And to protect your website from sql injection you may need to use prepared statements : [Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: how would a prepared statement prevent someone from changing an id in the url?

Comment: You are right I did not read the whole question :) I will update my post.

Comment: @Mehdi: Prepared statements are great for stopping sql injections, but they do nothing to stop userA from updating userB's information.

Comment: I would remove your answer, as may mislead people

Comment: or make it the better answer :) that is another option.